# Python with pytesseract - How to get the same output for pytesseract.image_to_data in a searchable PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, python-tesseract

I have this piece of code in Python that makes use of pytesseract (method pytesseract.image_to_data).

This gives me great text information and coordinates that are saved in a text file that is fed to a third party software. It works perfectly for PDF files that have been scanned

```
data = pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open('file-001-page-001.png')))
```

The issue now is that I have a demand for output in the exact same structure for PDFs that already contain text. It's possible to keep the same code and continue as if the PDF had no text, extracting images and doing OCR, but it doesn't seem like the right solution...

Is it possible to achieve this with pytesseract?
Suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

# Open the PDF file
with open('file.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    # Extract text from the PDF file and save it to a variable
    text = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(f, extension='hocr', lang='eng', config='--oem 3 --psm 6')

# Save the extracted text to a file in the desired format
with open('output.hocr', 'w')as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: Its almost what I needed... the only thing is that I need the same image_to_data output (boundary boxes and text), could you help-me?

Comment: Tried something similar but the method image_to_pdf_or_hocr does not accept a PDF file as input, it requires an Image as far as I know

Comment: I can't get your code to work, sorry. I was trying all day